# How to efficiently structure dynamic forms in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, html, webforms, django-forms

I am using Django.2x for my website. I have 15+ forms to be shown dynamically to the user based on the option he chooses from a dropdown. I have kept all the form-div's in one single html page and i am using JQuery to Show() and Hide() the forms based on the user's selection. Is there any better way where i can structure this flow of showing forms efficiently since my forms could increase soon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to load all the HTML at once, you could probably use AJAX to request the content you need, when you need it. Considering that the effect on page load speed wouldn't be that large, and you'd have to code in a view that would dynamically generate these forms (unless you want to code them in raw HTML, and upload them to your static files), I think your current approach may be the best way to go.